Handling large files upload using golang gin router
Assuming that I trust the content length.
I send a POST request to my gin server to upload files and other data. I added a middleware to check the content-length first; and if it is larger than my threshold, I return a 413 error to the user. Here's what I added:

On client:
I send formdata in the body.
I set the Expect:100-continue  header, so the client can know if the server will return the request before the client complete sends the whole body. Without that I get 503 Service Unavailable error when I send too large files.

On the server:
I added a middleware to check if the content length is accurate or not.


func SizeHandler() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if c.Request.ContentLength > MAX_FILE_SIZE {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusRequestEntityTooLarge, gin.H{"error": "Too large request"})
            return
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}


Problem:
When I try with postman, nearly all the times it gives me this error if I send too large files:
"Could not get response" Error: read ECONNRESET However I can see in the server logs that the server has responded.


I also tried to add in the middleware before returning:
c.Writer.Header().Set("Connection", "close")
io.Copy(io.Discard, c.Request.Body)
c.Request.Body.Close() 

But sometimes the server takes too extra time before responding, and when sending large files, the connection appears to be blocked and postman shows a 503 Service Unavailable.


HTTP spec doesn't allow for a response before the content has been read.  I suspect you might be running up against that problem.
